# What is the difference between a super capacitor, an ultra capacitor, and an industrial capacitor

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

What is the difference between super capacitors, ultra capacitors, industrial capacitors and hybrid capacitors?  I see these names thrown around but they seem to have blurred definitions.  Are there specific properties for each type?

Comment: show links if you want exact comparisons of these double electric layer dielectrics

Comment: also if you dont read the datasheets you cannot intelligently appreciate the answers.

Comment: The information you seek is easily derived from Google.

Comment: JBH, but I'm looking for more than Google's answers, there where the blurred definitions are coming from.  The industry seems to call their capacitors what they want.  In the Electronics world, are there definitive definitions?  What are YOUR definitions?

Comment: @JBH telling people to google things is not reccomended by SE

Comment: Actually, SE recommends that people do their own research before bringing questions to their sites.  That was the point I was making, and I apologize for not being clear about it.  Gratefully, the OP answered the issue by clarifying that he had done the research.

Comment: The blurred definitions you have found is actually the way things are; a great deal of overlap exists.